# How do I store the current value from a useState variable in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After an onClick event fires, I call the setInterval function which in turn calls a function to set the value for a variable picked randomly from an array of 4 values (4 different colors).  I need to keep track of what values were randomly selected. When I try to access the value of the getter variable returned from the useState hook by pushing it to my colortracker array, I see in the console that it's only storing empty strings in the array.

I've tried passing the bgCol variable in as a props value.  I've tried curly braces around bgCol.  Have tried defining my array with the keywords let and var.

```
function ColoredBox(props){

    return(
      <div style={{backgroundColor: props.color, marginBottom: 20, width: 
       200, height: 200}}>      
      </div>
    );
}

function Button(props){
    const start = () => {
        setInterval(props.startGame, 2000);
        }
    return(
        <button onClick={start} style={{marginBottom: 50}} >Start 
        Game</button>
  );
}



function Game(){
    const [bgCol, setbgCol]= useState('');
    const arr = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black'];
    const colortracker = [];     
    const handleClick = () => {     

        setbgCol(arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(4))]);
        colortracker.push(bgCol); 
        console.log(colortracker);    

    }
        return(
        <div>
            <ColoredBox color={bgCol} />
            <Button startGame={handleClick} />
        </div>
            );
      }

ReactDOM.render(<Game />,mountNode);
```

Actual output is an array filling up with empty strings as the values for bgCol when I need it to be strings representing the colors picked out of the arr array.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your handleClick is getting the first value of bgCol that is an empty string

try this

```
const handleClick = () => {

        const randomBgCol = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(4))];
        setbgCol(randomBgCol);
        colortracker.push(randomBgCol); 

        console.log(colortracker);    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue where `setState` is asynchronous. (The state changes *after* calling setState, not necessarily *right* after.)

You can use a local variable in your handleClick:

```
    const color = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(4))]
    setbgCol(color);
    colortracker.push(color); 
    console.log(colortracker);
```

Comment: Yes, that is what was happening.  Being a novice developer, I'm still learning how hooks work in React.  Your code worked for my situation.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem bud!